# Injecting a document.write call from a Greasemonkey script causes nothing to load

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, domdocument, userscripts

The following injection works perfectly in Chrome, however in the latest Firefox (version 21), the documents stays "Connecting..." forever and not even its elements like `<img>` loads. (But if you click reload on them they show up fine...)

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of problem]

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Test
// @namespace       Test
// @author          Owyn
// @match           http://*
// ==/UserScript==

function inject(func) {
    var source = func.toString();
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = "("+ source +")()";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function myf() {
  document.write('<html>TEST</html>');
}

inject(myf);
```

Any fixes, any workarounds? Should I contact Mozilla about a bug?

P.S. - I use document.write to remove all event listeners (unknown to me) and found no alternative to it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smartest/best(est) thing to do is to avoid `document.write()`.  **Use DOM techniques**. Here's **a complete script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Replace a target page using DOM techniques
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
var D       = document;
var newDoc  = D.implementation.createHTMLDocument ("");

D.replaceChild (
    D.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    D.documentElement
);

D.body.innerHTML = '<h1>TEST</h1>'
```

---

Greasemonkey normally fires on `DOMContentLoaded`, *not* when the page has fully completed loading.  Chrome fires later than that, by default.

Anyway, at `DOMContentLoaded`, in Firefox; something is getting orphaned when you trash the current document.  Hence the "throbber" is never stopped and some other cleanup is probably missed.

This is probably a bug, but you shouldn't use `document.write()` anyway.  Also, per [the DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write), you should call `document.close()`

A dirty workaround is to wait until the page has loaded before firing. So, instead of calling `inject(myf);` directly, call it like this:

```
function myf () {
  document.write ('<html>TEST</html>');
  document.close ();
}

window.addEventListener ("load", function () { inject(myf); }, false);
```

**but use DOM methods instead!**  They'll be faster, and won't trip edge-case bugs and security violations.

Comment: event load seem to fix it but now it waits for everything to long which may waste very long time, isn't there a way to fix it to work just like in Chrome? (page just opens and document.write works right away without freezing connection...)

Comment: Yes, use the DOM method.  That works in both browsers and doesn't require waiting for the `load` event.

Comment: What DOM method? The DOMContentLoaded which in FireFox corrupts the page to load infinitely and breake images?

Comment: Use the complete, working, script I gave in the 1st half of the answer. Do not use `document.write` at all.

Comment: implementation does not remove all event listeners unlike document.write so it does not server the purpose, instead for what it does I could just do document.body.innerHTML = "TEST";

Comment: I just tested it, both on window and document.head it leaves listeners, and also tested with document.write - all listeners were removed. I was asking about document.write forever-loading bug you just gave some random function which does exactly the same as document.body.innerHTML = ""; and nothing more. Sorry. Current answer is calling window.stop() and then with setTimeout edit document again to add images which would show fine (except reload function would still work badly or not at all)

Comment: Really?  Provide a test page that exhibits this event behavior. Note also that this event requirement **was not in the question** and belongs in a follow-up. And, no, my code is not *at all* the same thing as document.body.innerHTML ="", and there is no way it leaves anything on document head.  Finally, that is not all I "gave".  I provide the reason why your original code was failing AND a working workaround. And I tried to tell you that you should not use such poor techniques, even if the appear to work (for now) on Chrome.

Comment: document.addEventListener("click", function () { alert("Hi3"); }, false); - this stayes after implementation you posted but dissapears after document.write (tested both Chrome and FireFox) (not head yes, but pretty same, tested it some time ago and confused such small details). P.S. - you said not to use document.write but there is no alternative I found at this moment.